# Python Twisted Defer returnValue incompatible with dict

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted, twisted.internet

I am using `twisted.internet.defer` extensively in my package , I have encountered a problem which I am unable to solve after spending 2 days on it. Below is my problem scenario.

```
# all imports done and correct
class infrastructure: # line 1

  @inlineCallbacks
  def dict_service(self):
    client = MyClient()
    services = yield client.listServices() # line 5
    ret = (dict(service.name, [cont.container_id for cont in service.instances]) for service in dockerServices)
    returnValue(ret) # line 7
```

I am calling my client which returns me list of Services. `listServices()` return type is `twisted.internet.defer.ReturnValue` .

```
class myinterface:
   # has infrastructure

  def init:
     data = dict(
        container_services=self._infrastructure.dict_service(),
        )
```

when executing this I get below error which I am unable to comprehend. can someone please help.

```
raise TypeError(repr(o) + \" is not JSON serializable\")\nexceptions.TypeError: <DeferredWithContext at 0x4bfbb48 current result: <twisted.python.failure.Failure <type 'exceptions.NameError'>>> is not JSON serializable\n"
```

Is it because that wrapping `dict` with `returnValue` creating problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem using `returnValue` with a `dict` instance:

```
$ python -m twisted.conch.stdio
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks, returnValue
>>> @inlineCallbacks
... def f():
...     d = yield {"foo": "bar"} # Yield *something* or it's not a generator
...     returnValue(d)
... 
>>> f().addCallback(print)
{'foo': 'bar'}
<Deferred at 0x7f84c51847a0 current result: None>
```

The error you reported:

```
raise TypeError(repr(o) + \" is not JSON serializable\")\nexceptions.TypeError: <DeferredWithContext at 0x4bfbb48 current result: <twisted.python.failure.Failure <type 'exceptions.NameError'>>> is not JSON serializable\n"
```

Makes it appear as though you have some code that triggers a `NameError`.  This seems to happen in a Deferred callback (or otherwise makes its way into a Deferred) and gets wrapped in a `Failure`:

```
<twisted.python.failure.Failure <type 'exceptions.NameError'>>
```

That leaves:

```
raise TypeError(repr(o) + \" is not JSON serializable\")\nexceptions.TypeError: <DeferredWithContext at 0x4bfbb48 current result: ...> is not JSON serializable\n"
```

I don't know what `DeferredWithContext` is.  I'm guessing it's a subclass of `Deferred` with some additional behavior.  It'd be nice if you could link to the library that provides this (it seems like a bad idea to me but I'd like to understand more).

If that's so, then the error is talking about a `DeferredWithContext` instance that has the above-described `Failure` as its result:

```
<DeferredWithContext at 0x4bfbb48 current result: ...>
```

That leaves:

```
raise TypeError(repr(o) + \" is not JSON serializable\")\nexceptions.TypeError: ... is not JSON serializable\n"
```

This seems to come from the json module, either the `dump` or `dumps` function.  This is claiming something that is not JSON serializable was passed in.  `DeferredWithContext` is almost certainly not JSON serializable, so that explains the problem.

This would result from something like:

```
json.dumps(function_that_returns_deferred())
```

which should instead be:

```
function_that_returns_deferred().addCallback(json.dumps)
```

Comment: I do not have explicitly any json.dumps. but total stacktrace looks like this.

Comment: Something in your program must be doing _something_ with JSON.  Twisted itself certainly isn't trying to JSON serialize any values you yield from an inlineCallbacks-decorated function.

Comment: yes got it in-fact i was missing the returnValue in the callback. hence the problem. No json.dump anywhere provided in my code. Thanks.

Comment: Accepting this Answer since it helped me to solve my problem though solution was slightly different.